# Particular Solution By Method of Undetermined Coefficients Guess for Constant Exponential

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Am am trying to solve an ODE for a linear spring system.

on one side of the equation we have the $Mx''+Bx'+kx$ that you would use for the homogeneous part.

Now I am trying to solve for the Particular Solution for a force of $3e^{6+t}$
I thought I could use Method of Undetermined Coefficients, but I am not sure what kind of guess to make. I have already tried $$x_p(t)=Ae^{6+t}$$

Here's an example table of what I am talking about from a textbook I used for reference

[Example Guesses for g(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aprWe.png)
My $g(t)= 3e^{6+t}$

Any Suggestions? Shall I resort to another method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, realize that $Ae^{6+t} = Ae^6e^t = Ce^t.$

Second, if $e^t$ is one of the homogeneous solutions, then you'll have to multiply it by $t$ and use $Cte^t$.  Or even $Ct^2 e^t.$  It would help if posted the actual equation.

Comment: The equation is 30x′′+0x′+270x = 3e6+t (No damping). I apologize, I am brand new here. I don't want the solution, just a push in the right direction. I have deferred to using the wronskian method or whatever it is called in textbooks, however I feel this is less than ideal as the equation comes from a dynamics problem set which I would expect to have a neat easy to find solution.